# How to pass jquery variable value to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my javascript. I want to get jquery variable value to php variable in same page using ajax. I used  to print php variable but there is an error. I would be very grateful if anyone can help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#roomOptions #select1').change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select1').each(function() {
            total+=parseInt($(this).val());    
        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total').html(total);
        });         

    $('#roomOptions #select2').change(function() {
        var total1 = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select2').each(function() {
            total1+=parseInt($(this).val());    
        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total1').html(total1);
    });
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getrooms.php",
    data:{ total: total }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: *"There is a error in php variables called undefined index"* - Keep going... you didn't finish that. We're to debug this for you?

Comment: well there is no php here, please include it

Comment: @Dim5230 : You need to pass your final total value in hidden field and get  that value and pass that value in ajax call.

Comment: BTW, your `total` variable can be accessed only by the `change` method anonymous callback function!. `total` will be `undefined` in your ajax call.

Comment: <? php echo  $total = $_POST['total'];   ?>  This is my php code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add PHP somewhat like this:

```
<?php
$total = $_POST['total']  ;
echo $total;

?>
```

Comment: echo $id should be changed to echo $total;

Comment: Where does this `$id` come from?

Comment: Sorry in a hurry I typed, I made changes... Thank you.

Comment: I used php code like this but there is a error called Undefined index: total in...

Answer (score 0):

Adding edits as per the comments from question author.

Since you are using the same page for posting data using jquery, you should do a refresh of the page. Modify the code like this for the ajax call ( javascript part ).

```
$.post(window.location, {title: title}, success: function(data) {
  //do something here
});
```

And add this to the top of your pages code.

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['total'])) {
  echo $_POST['total'];
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: When did you get this error ? You tried accessing getrooms.php directly ?

Comment: Yes i used these functions in same page

Comment: No. You cant do that. If you want to POST using jquery to a PHP page, "getrooms.php" should be a different page.

Comment: How to it on same page?

Comment: In which part of i should include ajax part?

Comment: Remove 

$.ajax({
    url: 'getrooms.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "total": total
    }
});

and add the code from the updated answer.

Comment: I add full code of my javascript, Can you check is it right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

BTW, your `total` variable can be accessed only by the change method anonymous callback function!. `total` will be `undefined` in your ajax call.

```
$('#roomOptions #select1').change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('#roomOptions #select1').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total').html(total);

    $.ajax({
        url: getrooms.php,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "total": total
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There is a error in code called Undefined index: total in....                                     This is my php code <?php $total = $_POST['total'];   echo $total; ?>

Comment: Probably, `$_POST['total']` is undefined!. Can you echo `$_POST['total']`?, you can use `isset()` method to determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to use isset() method?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your 'total' variable in javascript before your function.

```
var total = 0;
$('#roomOptions #select1').change(function () {
    total = 0;
    $('#roomOptions #select1').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total').html(total);
});
```

Or get it before ajax init like that

```
  <script> 
    total = $("#roomOptions #roomOptions_total").html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getrooms.php",
        data:{ total: total }, 
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); 
        }
    })
    </script>
```

You can access your var in php

```
<?php echo $_POST['total']; ?>
```

You can see what inside total before ajax send it

```
 <script> 
        total = $("#roomOptions #roomOptions_total").html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getrooms.php",
            data: { total: total }, 
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data); 
            },
beforeSend: function() {
     console.log(total); 
  }
        })
        </script>
```

Comment: These javascript functions and php codes are in same page

Comment: It doesn't matter. Did you check whats inside total var before you send it ?

Comment: Undefined index: total

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your sequence of code. The ajax call is made before document.ready is called. If you convert it to something like this then may be it will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {
     var total = 0;
    $('#roomOptions #select1').change(function() {
         total = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select1').each(function() {
            total+=parseInt($(this).val());    
        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total').html(total);
        });         

    $('#roomOptions #select2').change(function() {
        var total1 = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select2').each(function() {
            total1+=parseInt($(this).val());    
        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total1').html(total1);
    });


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getrooms.php",
    data:{ total: total }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }
})
});
</script>
```